# getting error Too many positional args, still have while creating bigquery clustered tables

Tags: google-bigquery

As per BigQuery documentation [BQDoc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables) you can specify up to four clustering columns. In my case, I am executing below bq statement to create a clustered table but keep getting **Too many positional args, still have**

Here is bq CLI statement

```
bq mk --table --schema /tmpbq/schema_.json --time_partitioning_field effectivedate --clustering_fields departmentid,vendorid, markstyleid, colorcode  myproject-np:cat_dataset.cat_table
```

If I remove the last 2 or 1 clustered column then it works.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution - There should not be any space in comma-separated clustered columns

```
bq mk --table --schema /tmpbq/schema_.json --time_partitioning_field effectivedate --clustering_fields departmentid,vendorid,markstyleid,colorcode myproject-np:cat_dataset.cat_table
```

@GoogleTeam please mention this in the documentation.