# "Too many positional args, still have" - While running `bq mk --table` command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gitlab-ci, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to create a table in BigQuery with partitioning and clustering:

```
bq mk --table \
      --description "My table" \
      --schema $absolute_path \
      --clustering_fields user_email,referenced_project_id \
      --label label_app:bigquery-stats \
      --time_partitioning_field creation_time \
      --time_partitioning_type DAY \
      --require_partition_filter true \
      gcp-project.dataset.table
```

But I am getting the following error:
`Too many positional args, still have ['gcp-project.dataset.table']`

I tried re-arranging the flags but could not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `bq mk` command is ok except for the last line `gcp-project.dataset.table`. Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#create_an_empty_clustered_table_with_a_schema_definition), the project ID and dataset should be separated by a colon (`:`) instead of a dot/ period.

Try `gcp-project:dataset.table`

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772233/getting-error-too-many-positional-args-still-have-while-creating-bigquery-clust?rq=2) which also follows the same structure as `PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE`.

Sample:

> ```
> bq mk \
>    --table \
>    --schema PATH \
>    --clustering_fields CLUSTER_COLUMNS \
>    --description "DESCRIPTION" \
>    --label KEY:VALUE,KEY:VALUE \
>    PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE
> ```